# MySQL query for the following

Tags: mysql, select

I've a sample table"

```
A | 2
A | 0
A | 0
B | 1
B | 1
C | 2
C | 1
```

And I want Result to be:

```
A | 2
A | 0
A | 0
C | 2
C | 1
```

i.e,
I don't want the row which has same value in column two

Comment: Your table structure is unclear.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: Shouldn't other rows be removed, since they have the same values in column 2?

Comment: Why 2nd and 3rd lines in result didn't removed?

Comment: If the second column has more than one value for same value in column 1 then I want all to be selected

Comment: Since A - 2 then A - A-0 then I want all A's as 2 != 0 , same for C-2,C-1 but all B have same value in second column so all should be discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has columns 'ch' for the character and 'value' for the number you can do following:

```
select t.ch, t.value
from test t
  join (
    select ch, count(distinct value) as 'dst'
    from test
    group by ch
    having count(distinct value)=1
  ) as q on t.ch!=q.ch;
```

the subsuquery finds the ch's which only have one distinct value. Those are not included in the join.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most effective query but I guess you want something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE C1 NOT IN (
  SELECT C1 FROM test
  GROUP BY C1 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(C2)) = 1
);
```

I assume that you don't want the records with only 1 column one example; well if you do :

(for example if there is a "D | 1" row and you want that)

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE C1 NOT IN (
  SELECT C1 FROM test
  GROUP BY C1 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(C2)) = 1 AND COUNT(C2) > 1
);
```

Edit : Here is the [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4619a/1)